# OAuth multiple accounts login on deny

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, google-oauth

I'm developing a web platform and i noticed a weird behavior.

1. Open web browser
2. Go to website
3. Log in by Google
4. Log out
5. Log in on NEW account by Google
6. On permissions screen click on cancel

this will cause the user to login in the first account. Is this standard behaviour of Oauth?

Comment: Could you provide more information on how to reproduce this behavior? Are you using any client-side or server-side library to handle this flow? Is it using an authorization code flow?

Comment: We are using client side library, Owin Identity. This issue can be reproduced if we use two google accounts, one with access to the application and a second one without it. If we deny access on the second one, the first will be returned by the call to oauth.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is related to Google's own session management than it has to do with OpenID connect protocol.

OpenID Connect is gradually replacing OAuth 2.0 and Google had part in defining the new protocol.

You can see Google' fingerprint in the protocol exactly in the area you describe.
Handling the choice between multiple accounts.
Look at [3.1.2.1.  Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) on the field prompt, and consider why the value select_account is there.

Anyway the behavior you describe, in which the identity server is responding to an auth request with a valid code on an account that was recently logged out from, is incorrect.

Giving google the credit that it does comply with the protocol, I would suggest you look into the network communication and see if the google endpoint is actually returning a valid authentication for the  wrong user, or is it the relying party that keeps the old session.

Good Luck

Eyal

Comment: thanks for the response. I've already check the google servers response, and i get data for my first account, everything comes as if i selected it. Thats the reason why i think it is so odd. Testers also reported that this issue happens using facebook login, but that one i was unable to test it. We use Owin identity to manage the call.

Comment: I am not familiar with Owin identity. For this case, is a JavaScript library or .net library used?

Comment: In this case it is a .net library. it handles all the requests to google and facebook oauth automatically, but the problem here is the response we get from google, it has all the information about the first user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting. We'll look into this and respond back. I agree a user should not get signed into the first account when they see the approval page for account B and hit cancel.

We do optimize for the cases when a user is signed into two accounts and one account has already approved then we auto select that account.

Comment: Where is the auto select behaviour that you mention documented?

Comment: I'm not sure it is explicitly documented. but if you se this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state you'll get  a callback if a user signs in who has authorized your app (doesn't matter if it is user 1, 2 , 3 if there are multi logged in users)

Comment: Many thanks for the link. May I humbly suggest that all behaviours need to be documented somewhere, especially where it pertains to security..

Comment: Thanks, i will waiting for your feedback related to this issue.